# android Wait between GridView updates

Tags: java, android, multithreading, gridview, android-adapter

I have a GridView of TextViews, I want to iterate though each TextView, change it's background, wait for 1 second, and go to the next TextView and do the same thing.

First start off with none of the TextViews being colored

[image: SoE1]

Then I want to color the first TextView

[image: SoE2]

Now I want to wait for one second...

and afterwards.

[image: SoE3]

And repeat with the remaining TextViews.

The problem is, `MainActivity.playSoE()`, the method that does updating of the grid, uses `notifyDataSetChanged()` to update the GridView. Which makes threading more of an issue. Everything I've tried either causes an Exception or freezes everything and skips the intermediate steps until the whole Grid is colored. I've tried using `Activity.runOnUiThread()`, `wait()`, `Thread.sleep()` and tried making a new `Thread` but none of these has worked for me. I

And to clarify, I want to be able to communicate with the rest of the app while the Grid is being colored, I don't want the entire app freezing on me.

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private boolean mIsPlaying;
    private int primesLE;
    private GridView mGridView;
    private ImageAdapter mAdapter;
    private Thread mThread;

    private void dataVisualization(){

        int numOfColumns = (int)Math.round(Math.sqrt((double) primesLE));
        //int numOfRows = (int)Math.ceil((double)primesLE/(double)numOfColumns);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams;

        layoutParams = mGridView.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.width = 150*numOfColumns; //this is in pixels
        mGridView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        mGridView.setNumColumns(numOfColumns);
        mAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, primesLE);
        mGridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mIsPlaying = false;
        primesLE = 0;


        View relativeLayout = findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
        View title_horizontalScrollView = relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.title_horizontalScrollView);
        View dataLayout = title_horizontalScrollView.findViewById(R.id.dataLayout);
        mGridView = (GridView) dataLayout.findViewById(R.id.mGridView);

        dataVisualization();

        View inputLayout = relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.inputLayout);
        final EditText inputEditText = (EditText)inputLayout.findViewById(R.id.inputEditText);
        inputEditText.setOnKeyListener(new EditText.OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
                if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                        (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                    // Perform action on key press

                    InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(inputEditText.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);

                    try {
                        primesLE = Integer.parseInt(inputEditText.getText().toString());
                    } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
                        inputEditText.setText("Try again");
                        primesLE = 0;
                    }
                    if(primesLE < 0)
                        primesLE = 0;

                    dataVisualization();

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, inputEditText.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        inputEditText.setOnClickListener(new EditText.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                inputEditText.getText().clear();
            }
        });
    }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void playSoE(){

        for(int i = 0; i < primesLE; i++) {
            mAdapter.setPositionColor(i, 0xffff0000 + 0x100 * i); //calls notifyDataSetChanged()
             new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                     notifyDataSetChanged();
                 }
             }, 1000);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        Log.d("Menu","Button Pressed");
        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        else if (id == R.id.action_status){
            if(mIsPlaying) {
                mIsPlaying = false;
                item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_play);
                item.setTitle("Play");
                playSoE();
            }
            else {
                mIsPlaying = true;
                item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_pause);
                item.setTitle("Pause");
            }
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

ImageAdapter.java:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private int mCount;
    private boolean setBlueBackground = false;
    private int[] gridColors;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c, int resource, int count) {
        super(c, resource);
        mContext = c;
        mCount = count;
        gridColors = new int[mCount];
        Arrays.fill(gridColors,Color.LTGRAY);
    }


    public int getCount() {
        return mCount;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView textView;

        if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            textView = new TextView(mContext);
            textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            textView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));

        } else {
            textView = (TextView) convertView;
        }


        textView.setBackgroundColor(gridColors[position]);

        textView.setText("" + position);
        return textView;
    }

    public void setPositionColor(int position, int color) {
        gridColors[position] = color;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/inputLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#a9a9a9"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:text="All primes less than\n or equal to this number:"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />



        <!-- Dummy item to prevent AutoCompleteTextView from receiving focus -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:focusable="true" android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="0px"
            android:inputType="numberSigned"/>

        <!-- :nextFocusUp and :nextFocusLeft have been set to the id of this component
             to prevent the dummy from receiving focus again -->

        <AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/autotext"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:nextFocusUp="@id/autotext" android:nextFocusLeft="@id/autotext"
            android:inputType="numberSigned" android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:inputType="numberSigned"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/inputEditText"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/autotext"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView" />

    </RelativeLayout>


    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/inputLayout"

        android:id="@+id/title_horizontalScrollView"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MainActivity"
            android:id="@+id/dataLayout"
            >

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/mGridView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:columnWidth="90dp"
                android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
                android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

menu_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_status"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_play"
        android:title="Play"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/action_stop"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_stop"
        android:title="Stop"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
            android:title="@string/action_settings"
            app:showAsAction="never"  />

    </menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Handler to delay and perform your action

**Edited**

```
for(int i = 0; i < primesLE; i++) {

         new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                 mAdapter.setPositionColor(i, 0xffff0000 + 0x100 * i);
                 notifyDataSetChanged();
             }
         }, 1000);

    }
```

This will execute for 1 second and will update the data

Comment: change your arraylist for one and then call this method and then for another you would have to perform this in a for loop where you update every arraylist

Comment: What do you mean changing my arraylist? I'm not using any ArrayLists here. Also I am using a for loop to call the handler, once for each update. You can see it in `MainActivity.playSoE()`

Comment: I've added your code into mine to show you what I tried.

Comment: please check i updated my answer you can do the changes as per my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately you should switch to using a RecyclerView with a GridLayoutManager. The RecyclerView offers very flexible methods for updating the UI. In your case, notifyItemChanged(int position) would efficiently update one single TextView. Find out more [here](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html#RecyclerView).